# pycharm can't set interpreter 'python 3.10'

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm using pycharm community edition for learning, so I installed python 3.10.8 first! In the progress, I checked on 'Add Python 3.10 to PATH' and also checked that it is installed and working in cmd succesfully! So I installed Pycharm Community Edition too. But I tried to set up the System interpreter in the setting, but it didn't work.

python.exe file address is simple, even not a hidden file. but it can't find interpreter even it right under drive c:

How can i fix it? Let me know if I missed anything in the process.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: as I rember you can manually search interpreter in PyCharm or you can manually put `c:/full/path/to/python.exe`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.